# How to give discount on package subscription in revenuecat flutter?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I am using Revenuecat for flutter. During package subscription I want to give certain discount to the users while purchasing. Is there any way to give discount from client side on package subscription?

Comment: You want to give a discount for a one time purchase to a user IF he/she is already subscribed, while non-subscribed users get to pay full price for that one time item? Is this correct?

Comment: Considering my yearly subscription package default price is $98. I want to give a discount to the users who subscribed to the package in January. Users who subscribed in January will have to pay only $48 for the whole year. After then they will pay the regular price. How can I achieve this is google play and apply pay in app purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [iOS subscription offers](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/ios-subscription-offers), or [iOS offer codes](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/ios-subscription-offers#2-redeeming-an-offer-code), and [Android promo codes](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/android-promo-codes) which are not exactly what you want.

As far as I know, Apple and Google subscriptions are period based (monthly/yearly) only, compared to calendar based ("subscribe for this year").

What I would do is create a subscription offer that last a certain number of months and after those months it becomes full price. The certain number of months (and the offer price) depends on how far you are in the year.